# Neo4J stacked query for desicion tree and expert system

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I am new to Neo4J and struggling to get the output I need without extra external processing. I am pretty sure that Neo4J is easily capable of doing that. Please advice on best approach.

I have a 2 types of nodes: Ingredient and Function that are connected using relation that has property of {Weight: 1}. I am querying a list of ingredients and I want to get a sum of connections multiplied by weight of each connection leading to each distinct function.

Here's what I came up with.

```
MATCH (q:Ingredient)-[r]->(p) WHERE q.RefNo IN [1,2,3]  RETURN r,p
```

This produces following output

```
{"weight":1}│{"Function":"X1"}                                                    
{"weight":0.5}│{"Function":"X1"}                                                                
{"weight":0.7}│{"Function":"X2"}
{"weight":0.4}│{"Function":"X3"}
{"weight":0.5}│{"Function":"X4"}
```

What I want to get in a single/stacked query is

```
X1:1.5, X2:1=0.7, X3:0.4, X4:0.5
```

Please advice on possible solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there, you just need to use an aggregation function (in this case, `sum()`) on the weight, and the `Function` property as your non-aggregation column:

```
MATCH (q:Ingredient)-[r]->(p) 
WHERE q.RefNo IN [1,2,3]  
RETURN p.Function, sum(r.weight) as weight
```

Or if you only want a single row result:

```
MATCH (q:Ingredient)-[r]->(p) 
WHERE q.RefNo IN [1,2,3]  
WITH p, sum(r.weight) as weight
RETURN collect(p {.Function, weight}) as functionWeights
```

Comment: Not, actually. Second option doesn't – "You can't use arrogate functions inside aggregate functions". But that is solvable with WITH.